# How does the bounty system resolve ties between two answers after the grace period expires?

Tags: support, bounty, help-center

In the event that both a bounty and its subsequent grace period expire without an explicit award or accepted answer, the help section [How is a bounty rewarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) describes how the system automatically awards 1/2 of the bounty and under what conditions:

> ... the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 ... If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

From the explanation, however, **it is unclear how the award will be made in the event of [a tie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474373/add-certificate-exception-in-iframe/23649216#23649216)**.

In the linked SO question, no answers had been accepted and mine was one of two answers that were both:

- Answered within the active bounty period, and
- Receiving a score of at least (in this case, exactly) +2 by the end of the bounty

My interpretation is that this result was a *two-way tie* for "highest scored", according to the bounty rules.  Eventually, the bounty was awarded to *only the other user's answer*.

While I am admittedly trying to increase my rep in any legitimate way, let me be clear that my intent with this question is *not* to complain or whine about not receiving the bounty in this particular case.  However, I'd like to discover what *actually* breaks the tie or if the decision is arbitrary -- or (unlikely?) a bug.  In any case, I think the language in the help page could be more clear, or details added, to explain the expected behavior in this case.

There are perfectly legitimate (or at least plausible) reasons why the other answer should "win" over mine:

- The other answer was posted prior to mine.
- The other answer reached +2 votes prior to mine.
- The other user has more rep.
- SO naively awards the answer chosen by something like `SELECT answer FROM ... WHERE score >= 2 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1` (which may be deterministic depending on the PK or index order, but is otherwise arbitrary without that knowledge)

Regarding the language on the help page, the use of the word "the" in `the highest voted answer` *could* be interpreted as the *single* highest voted answer.  Under that interpretation ties are precluded and neither answer should be awarded, but that does not match the observed behavior.  A more liberal interpretation would be that *all* `N>=1` answers that *share* the same highest score should each get 1/2 of the bounty amount.  That, too, does not match the observed behavior.  So...

1. I don't expect so, but is it a bug?
2. If not, then this is intentional behavior. What is the actual criteria used to break ties for automatically awarded bounties?
3. How to go about updating the help page to explain the expected outcome in this edge case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've updated the help center to reflect that in the event of a tie, the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

Comment: What if two answers have exactly the same timestamp?

Comment: @usr: One of them still has a lower post ID.

Answer (score 8):

> If two or more eligible answers have the same score (if their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)